# Group by on bits of an integer column in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, bit-manipulation

I have a table with an integer primary key, and an integer column.

```
+---------------------+-------------+
|       EmployeeId    | hour_bitmap |
+---------------------+-------------+
|         10001       |       1     |
|         10002       |   33554431  |
+---------------------+-------------+
```

its a table which stores the specific hours worked by an employee every day in a hour_bitmap.
For example for the first employee has a value of 1 so he works only in the 0th hour, whereas the employee 10002 has the value 33554431 = (1<<25)-1, for which the bit sequence is 1...24times, so he works all the 24 hours.

Is there a way groupby on hourId in mysql?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, there is not a "good" way, because the data structure is bogus.  Someone is obviously trying to over-optimize SQL and using a non-relational structure in doing so.  Arrgg!

Can you do it?  Yes, of course.  Here is one way:

```
select h.hh, count(t.employeeid)
from (select 0 as hh union all select 1 union all select 2 union all select 3 . . .
      select 23
     ) h left join
     t
     on t.hour_bitmap & (1 << h.hh) > 0
group by h.hh;
```